# Removing tranpose by multiplying

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem understanding this rule, that my professor wrote up:
$$\vec{x}^TB\vec{y}=\vec{x}\cdot(B\vec{y}),$$
when $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. I can't find an example where this is correct, fx.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 g \\
 h \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 (a c+b e) g+(a d+b f) h \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
however,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 g \\
 h \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a (c g+d h) \\
 b (e g+f h) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
does not give the same. Any idea on why it doesn't give the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}$, we mean the dot product $\vec{v}^\top \vec{w}$.
So $\vec{x}^\top B \vec{y}$ is literally the same as $\vec{x} \cdot (B \vec{y})$.

You should not use "$\cdot$" for usual matrix multiplication.

So you should have written
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 g \\
 h \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 (a c+b e) g+(a d+b f) h \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
which is correct, and the second one should be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a&
 b
\end{array}
\right)  \left(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 g \\
 h \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)=
( a (c g+d h) +
 b (e g+f h))$$

Comment: Thank you for the fast help! It really makes sense now.